# Problems with SharedPreferences

Tags: android, int, sharedpreferences

I've been trying to get this to work for a long time, I've checked every question I can find yet as this isn't giving me any errors I don't have much to work from! Basically, I have a button that adds one to an int, which is displayed in a TextView next to it. I'd like this int to stay when the app is closed, so it looks like sharedpreferences is my best option (I also considered sqlite but I'm not certain about whether it can be edited without updating the app, and this just looks easier).

So, my problem is that the int gets increased fine but resets to 0 when I press the back button/close the app etc.

Here's the activity that this is all happening in. EDIT: This is my code so far (with more else ifs)

```
package com.example.myapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class ThirdScreenActivity extends Activity {

    public int intPlusOne;
    public int intPlusOne2;
    public static final String PREFS = "MyPrefsFile";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.screen2);

        //Sets the title to recipe name
        TextView t = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textviewPosition));

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String position = intent.getStringExtra("position");

        t.setText(position);       

        //Sets the correct recipe
    if ("ListView Item 1".equals(position)) {

        TextView t1 = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView1));
        t1.setText(R.string.string1, null); 

        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences(PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
        intPlusOne = sharedPrefs.getInt("intPlusOneSaved", 0);

        TextView PlusOne = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.plusonetextview));
        PlusOne.setText(String.valueOf(intPlusOne));

        Button PlusOneButton = ((Button)findViewById(R.id.plusonebutton));
        PlusOneButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                intPlusOne++;

            TextView PlusOne = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.plusonetextview));
            PlusOne.setText(String.valueOf(intPlusOne));            
            }
        });
    }

    else if ("ListView Item 2".equals(position)) {

        TextView t1= ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView1));
        t1.setText(R.string.string2, null); 

        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("PREFS", MODE_PRIVATE);
        intPlusOne2 = sharedPrefs.getInt("intPlusOne2Saved", 0);

        TextView PlusOne = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.plusonetextview));
        PlusOne.setText(String.valueOf(intPlusOne2));

        Button PlusOneButton = ((Button)findViewById(R.id.plusonebutton));
        PlusOneButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            intPlusOne2++;

            TextView PlusOne = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.plusonetextview));
            PlusOne.setText(String.valueOf(intPlusOne2));           
            }
        }); 
    }

   public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences(PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
        Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
        editor.putInt("intPlusOneSaved", intPlusOne);
        editor.commit(); //also tried removing this line
        editor.putInt("intPlusOne2Saved", IntPlusOne2);
        editor.commit();
}
```

}

I'd be happy to provide any more details if it helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `onDestroy` is not always called at the end of an activity. You can try to put your code in the `onPause` method:

```
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    String PlusOneString = String.valueOf(intPlusOne);
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences(PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
    Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
    editor.putString("PlusOneSaved", PlusOneString);
    editor.commit();

}
```

EDIT:

You don't get the saved value in the `onCreate` method. Try something like this:

```
package com.example.myapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class ThirdScreenActivity extends Activity {

    public int intPlusOne;
    public static final String PREFS = "MyPrefsFile";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.screen2);

    if ("ListView Item 1".equals(position)) {

        TextView tv = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView1));
        tv.setText(R.string.name, null); 

        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences(PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
        intPlusOne = sharedPrefs.getInt("PlusOneSaved", 0);

        TextView PlusOne = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.plusonetextview));
        PlusOne.setText(String.valueOf(intPlusOne));

        Button PlusOneButton = ((Button)findViewById(R.id.plusonebutton));
        PlusOneButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            intPlusOne++;

            TextView PlusOne = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.plusonetextview));
            PlusOne.setText(String.valueOf(intPlusOne));            
            }
        });
    }

public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences(PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
        Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
        editor.putInt("PlusOneSaved", intPlusOne);
        editor.commit();

    }   
}
```

EDIT 2: Put these 2 lines before the first `if`:

```
intPlusOne = sharedPrefs.getInt("intPlusOneSaved", 0);
intPlusOne2 = sharedPrefs.getInt("intPlusOne2Saved", 0);
```

The complete code:

```
package com.example.myapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class ThirdScreenActivity extends Activity {

public int intPlusOne;
public int intPlusOne2;
public static final String PREFS = "MyPrefsFile";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.screen2);

    //Sets the title to recipe name
    TextView t = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textviewPosition));

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String position = intent.getStringExtra("position");

    t.setText(position);    

    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences(PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
    intPlusOne = sharedPrefs.getInt("intPlusOneSaved", 0);
    intPlusOne2 = sharedPrefs.getInt("intPlusOne2Saved", 0); 

    //Sets the correct recipe
    if ("ListView Item 1".equals(position)) {

        TextView t1 = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView1));
        t1.setText(R.string.string1, null); 

        TextView PlusOne = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.plusonetextview));
        PlusOne.setText(String.valueOf(intPlusOne));

        Button PlusOneButton = ((Button)findViewById(R.id.plusonebutton));
        PlusOneButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                intPlusOne++;

                TextView PlusOne = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.plusonetextview));
                PlusOne.setText(String.valueOf(intPlusOne));            
            }
        });
    }

    else if ("ListView Item 2".equals(position)) {

        TextView t1= ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView1));
        t1.setText(R.string.string2, null); 

        TextView PlusOne = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.plusonetextview));
        PlusOne.setText(String.valueOf(intPlusOne2));

        Button PlusOneButton = ((Button)findViewById(R.id.plusonebutton));
        PlusOneButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                intPlusOne2++;

                TextView PlusOne = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.plusonetextview));
                PlusOne.setText(String.valueOf(intPlusOne2));           
            }
        }); 
    }

    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences(PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
        Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
        editor.putInt("intPlusOneSaved", intPlusOne);
        editor.putInt("intPlusOne2Saved", IntPlusOne2);
        editor.commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, you've solved it! I'm not sure whether it was the onDestroy/onPause fix or something else but I spent many many hours on this, thanks very much.

Comment: You didn't initialize your `intPlusOne` attribute in your `onCreate` method.

Comment: Hmm, I have another small problem but I'm not sure whether to ask another question or whether it's something quickly solveable. I have more than one "if x equals position" (using else if) and they each work fine on their own, even when the app is closed, but if I +1 one item, go back and +1 another, the first one resets to 0! Could you help please? (See edited question)

Comment: Can you post your `else if`?

Comment: It's a direct copy and paste of the `if`, just with changed variable names. I'll edit it into the question anyway though

Comment: You still use `intPlusOne` in the `else if`. Replace all `intPlusOne` by `intPlusOne2`.

Comment: ah sorry, just a typo when I was putting the code into stackoverflow, I've changed that now

Comment: You have to initialize `intPlusOne` and `intPlusOne2` before the first `if`. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much again, I'm still getting to grips with android so thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

This is simple
you made a big mistake.

```
    String PlusOneString = String.valueOf(intPlusOne);
    Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
    editor.putString("PlusOneSaved", PlusOneString);
    editor.commit();
```

this code is in onCreate so it saves the value only on application start, when the value is incremented the preferences never got updated

Solution: update the preferences when you increment the value

```
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs;//create it outside on create for accessing in on click event


    PlusOneButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        intPlusOne++;

        TextView PlusOne = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.plusonetextview));
        PlusOne.setText(String.valueOf(intPlusOne));

        /// IMPORTANT PART SAVE THE VALUE TO PREFERENCES
        String PlusOneString = String.valueOf(intPlusOne);
        Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
        editor.putString("PlusOneSaved", PlusOneString);
        editor.commit();

        }});
```

Comment: one more thing you can also use "putInt & getInt" instead of "putString & getString"

Comment: I'd tried getInt and it hadn't worked, presumably I'd messed that up too! So would the editor lines at the end go inside onClick? (and thanks for the quick response)

Comment: Okay, I tried this and it works perfectly when I switch pages in the app. However, if I close the app (by pressing the back button on the first page) it seems to reset it and it's back at 0 when I go back!

Comment: try to log the value of sharedPrefs.getInt("PlusOneSaved", 0); and check is it saving or not, if its saving correctly then your activity is not reading the value on application start.
you can check the code by using log after everytime you change the value & preferences.
also may i know why you are using this if code - if ("ListView Item 1".equals(position))

Comment: That code was because the previous activity is a listview and this is the page that appears when you click an item. that sets the title and other features to the correct values on click, as I have other 'else if' statements in the activity but I removed them to make it easier to answer this question. Back to this question, Addrallyn's answer solves my problem completely so I'll mark his as the answer, although thank you for your quick reply and the help which may well have worked if I'd followed it through more.

Comment: Its ok mark his answer correct, i am not frequent on stackoverflow, but i don't see any difference in his answer. Good Luck